# What's the difference between Program AE (mode P) and ISO priority?

Tags: iso

In both of them you choose an iso, and the camera automatically set shutter speed and aperture. So what's the difference?

I'm using Canon EOS 4000D, where there is only Program AE (mode P), but I've seen ISO priority in other cameras. So I was wondering about the difference, if there is any.

Comment: What camera/brand?

Comment: Canon EOS 4000D

Comment: I've encountered "Auto ISO", but not "ISO priority". Can you name a camera with this mode, just for reference? Thanks

Comment: Don't remember the camera, but I think you are right on the fact it was called "auto ISO"

Comment: Well, then that's a totally different question. Auto ISO is where the camera chooses the ISO (possibly within user-set bounds), according to some algorithm. It can be used together with any of the PASM exposure modes. Personally I shoot in M mode together with Auto ISO - it allows me to set the aperture I want, and then influence the camera's choice of ISO by easy manipulation of the shutter speed.

Comment: So it seem to understand auto iso is a very different thing and there isn't really something like iso priority in any cameras, while the program AE is the closest to what could be considered a iso priority...

Comment: ISO priority is the default... (and that's also the behavior of a film camera):  in P/Av/Tv modes you set the ISO and the camera won't change it on its own, so ISO priority is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a camera with an ISO priority mode; but I've often mentally called Programmable Auto (P) mode exactly that, since you are choosing your ISO and the camera can shift all the other settings around to get to good exposure.

"Auto ISO", however, is a completely different thing.  Auto ISO is where the camera can select the ISO setting, usually bounded by limits you set.  So, the ISO setting is *not* given priority and locked down, as aperture and shutter settings are in aperture-priority and shutter-priority modes, respectively.